# On isomorphic normal subgroups of a group

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Well this is quite stupid a question because the intuition is false. See comments and answers below.

Original question:

> Consider $H_1,H_2\le G$, $H_1 \cong H_2$. It seems trivial that if $H_1 \unlhd G$, then $H_2 \unlhd G$, but how can I give a rigorous proof? I'm stuck after I write $\varphi(gH_1g^{-1})=\varphi(H_1)=H_2 $ because I don't know whether $\varphi$ can be an automorphism (so that all elements in $G$ can be written as $\varphi(g)$ for some $g$).

Comment: I don't have a counterexample but I'm pretty sure this statement is false.

Comment: Hint: try enumerating the subgroups of the dihedral group of order $8$, and see if your statement holds.

Comment: You‘re misusing the word „trivial“.

Comment: Oh thanks! Now this seems to be a stupid question.

Comment: I totally agree that that statement feels like it should be true at first! As you note, the problem is pretty much exactly that you can't guarantee that the isomorphism extends to a $G$-automorphism. In fact, "there is a $G$-automorphism taking $H_1$ to $H_2$" is usually the right hypothesis for statement like this. Another example arises whenever $G \rtimes G$ is an indirect semidirect product (eg $\Bbb Z \rtimes \Bbb Z$). Here's a similar fact: If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are isomorphic normal subgroups, we needn't have $G/N_1 \cong G/N_2$! (not even if we assume everything is finite!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It seems trivial that if $H_1 \unlhd G$, then $H_2 \unlhd G$

You mean trivially false. ;)

Consider any group $G$ with a subgroup $H\subseteq G$ which **is not** normal. Then consider $G\times H$. With this we have that $\{e\}\times H$ is normal in $G\times H$, but $H\times\{e\}$ is not, even though they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

As a counter-example, Klein 4-group embeds into $S_4$ as the normal$^\dagger$ subgroup:
$$H_0:=\{(),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$$
and the three non normal subgroups:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&H_1:=\{(),(12),(34),(12)(34)\} \\
&H_2:=\{(),(13),(24),(13)(24)\} \\
&H_3:=\{(),(14),(23),(14)(23)\} \\
\end{alignat}

---

$^\dagger$In fact, in $S_n$ conjugation preserves the cycle type, and the nontrivial elements of $H_0$ exhaust all the double transpositions of $S_4$.